# update progress bar when download file in android

Tags: java, android, download, progress-bar, progress

I try to download a file using services in android... I was able to write the program and I can download what ever I want. but the problem is with the progress bar!!!
I'm not able to define the total file length (or size) and the current downloaded size.
I used this code to get the file lenght

```
            URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
```

and I used this part of code to define the current downloaded size

```
           InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
           OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/BarcodeScanner-debug.apk");

           byte data[] = new byte[1024];
           long total = 0;
           int count;
           while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
               total += count;
               int currentValue=(total * 100 / fileLength);
               output.write(data, 0, count);
           }
```

the problem is that at the end of download I got something like 241% instead of 100% (because the fileLength for ex was around 12226 and the total was 29349)
Do you have any idea about this topic.

Comment: could you please share your code how you are showing progress and also verify does the downloading url supports `getContentLength`

Answer (score 0):

checkout this links for your reference

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-download-progress-bar/